# Unable to see sourceMaps for ts files

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

I recently upgraded my app to Angular 7 and now I am unable to view sourceMaps component.ts files are missing.
No webpack:// on my Chrome sources.
All I see are component.ngfactory.js

I am using ng serve to run my app.

Comment: thats usually an indication it's running in production mode and not debug

Comment: It is in dev mode 
I see the below msg in terminal 
Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/dist/apps/example**

Comment: in the browser's dev tools are you seeing a Angular Dev message?

Comment: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? Have the same problem now. Did you introduce firebase at some point?